Error Nginx: stat() failed (13: permission denied)
This is my first setup web server & dns server, I'm using:

nginx
php7.4 (shivammathur/php/php@7.4)

And I've problem while setup my local app to run multiple app:

yii 1 (/Users/ademugnirusmana/Project/www/wms) => www.wms.local
laravel 7 (/Users/ademugnirusmana/Project/www/middleware) => www.middleware.local
codeigniter 3 (/Users/ademugnirusmana/Project/www/reporting) => www.reporting.local

When I try using command php -S localhost:8080 inside directory of yii project, everthing work well, but when I call the domain in the browser (www.wms.local), there is an error "File not found"
Here my config nginx (sample for yii):
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.wms.local;
        root /Users/ademugnirusmana/Projects/www/wms;
        index index.php;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }

Here config host
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
#127.0.0.1      localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       www.wms.local
#127.0.0.1      www.reporting.local
#127.0.0.1      www.middleware.local

Here the fpm config "usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php-fpm.d/www.conf"
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

Here the fpm "ps aux| grep nginx"
ademugnirusmana  16744   0.0  0.0 34130864    468 s000  S+   11:24am   0:00.01 tail -f /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log
nobody           15649   0.0  0.0 34161744   1396   ??  S    11:18am   0:00.01 nginx: worker process
root              9749   0.0  0.0 34161536   1544   ??  Ss   10:24am   0:00.01 nginx: master process nginx
ademugnirusmana  17616   0.0  0.0 34141260    916 s001  S+   11:35am   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox --exclude-dir=.venv --exclude-dir=venv nginx

Here the permission of the directory (sample yii)
drwxr-xr-x  18 nobody  nobody  576 25 Nov 10:52 /Users/ademugnirusmana/Projects/www/wms

Here the log from "nginx"
2024/11/25 11:29:34 [crit] 15649#0: *52 stat() "/Users/ademugnirusmana/Projects/www/wms/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.wms.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.wms.local"
2024/11/25 11:29:34 [error] 15649#0: *52 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.wms.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.wms.local"

Here the log from "fpm"
[25-Nov-2024 11:40:35] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[25-Nov-2024 11:40:35] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[25-Nov-2024 11:40:35] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[25-Nov-2024 11:40:35] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[25-Nov-2024 11:40:35] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:9000': Address already in use (48)
[25-Nov-2024 11:40:35] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:9000': Address already in use (48)
[25-Nov-2024 11:40:35] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[25-Nov-2024 11:40:35] ERROR: FPM initialization failed

Can someone help me where I've done wrong with the config or anything to fix?
Additional Notes:
I've setup on mac Monterey 12.7.6 (Intel Chipset)

Every single directory up to the file has to be accessible by nobody. Your home directory probably isn’t. Either grant permissions to every directory in the chain or put the files to a better location.

It seems that your php-fpm is unable to start since something is already using port 9000. Either switch to a different port or free port 9000 and try again.
You can use netstat to find out which process is using port 9000:
sudo netstat -vanp tcp |grep :9000

Also, make sure that your project is in /Users/ademugnirusmana/Projects/www/wms and maybe enclose it in quotes and add a trailing slash.
The nginx config that you pasted above is not the one invoked when running php -S localhost:8080, because that commands connects to port 8080 and your nginx config is set to listen on port 80.

Change permissions for the other users and group for /Users/ademugnirusmana/Projects/www/ location.
chmod -R go+r /Users/ademugnirusmana/Projects/www/

